# 403 Forbidden - Access to this resource on the server is denied - PHP

Tags: php, json, post, http-status-code-403

I am trying to make a POST request. I do it using android but I checked also with Postman and I have the same results.

I checked similar answers but nothing helped. What drives me crazy is this:

I get the 403 error when I post a request using this JSON data:

```
{
   "exercisesList":[
      {
         "isFavorite":0,
         "isLiked":0,
         "isUploaded":0,
         "allBookPages":0,
         "bookID":"",
         "bookPages":"",
         "data":"[{\"image\":\"149951.jpg\",\"isCorrect\":1,\"position\":0,\"text\":\"\"},{\"image\":\"2629361.jpg\",\"isCorrect\":0,\"position\":1,\"text\":\"\"}]",
         "dateAdded":"2021-11-01 02:14:06",
         "endVideoSecond":0,
         "exerciseID":"4OEgiM7NizWGER9v7ttJdUQaUCl21635725646363",
         "exerciseType":0,
         "genre":0,
         "isPublic":1,
         "isTrue":-1,
         "language":17,
         "mainText":"select only numbers",
         "maxAge":2,
         "minAge":1,
         "startVideoSecond":0,
         "subtitle":"",
         "teacherID":"4OEgiM7NizWGER9v7ttJdUQaUCl2",
         "videoDuration":0,
         "videoID":"",
         "videoTitle":""
      }
   ],
   "lessonItem":{
      "dateAdded":"2021-11-06 11:59:03",
      "estimatedEnergy":7,
      "exercises":"{4OEgiM7NizWGER9v7ttJdUQaUCl21635725646363}",
      "exercisesTypes":"{0}",
      "genre":3,
      "isPublic":1,
      "language":17,
      "lessonID":"4OEgiM7NizWGER9v7ttJdUQaUCl2133341170864824",
      "maxAge":8,
      "minAge":6,
      "teacherID":"4OEgiM7NizWGER9v7ttJdUQaUCl2",
      "title":"Test lesson 407",
      "totalExercises":1,
      "totalUpvotes":0
   }
}
```

But I don't get a 403 error when I post a request with this JSON data:

```
{
   "exercisesList":[
      {
         "isFavorite":0,
         "isLiked":0,
         "isUploaded":0,
         "allBookPages":0,
         "bookID":"",
         "bookPages":"",
         "data":"[{\"correct\":0,\"text\":\"one\"},{\"correct\":1,\"text\":\"two\"},{\"correct\":0,\"text\":\"three\"}]",
         "dateAdded":"2021-11-06 12:24:02",
         "endVideoSecond":0,
         "exerciseID":"4OEgiM7NizWGER9v7ttJdUQaUCl21636194242562",
         "exerciseType":2,
         "genre":0,
         "isPublic":1,
         "isTrue":-1,
         "language":17,
         "mainText":"test mult",
         "maxAge":2,
         "minAge":1,
         "startVideoSecond":0,
         "subtitle":"",
         "teacherID":"4OEgiM7NizWGER9v7ttJdUQaUCl2",
         "videoDuration":0,
         "videoID":"",
         "videoTitle":""
      }
   ],
   "lessonItem":{
      "dateAdded":"2021-11-06 12:23:28",
      "estimatedEnergy":16,
      "exercises":"{4OEgiM7NizWGER9v7ttJdUQaUCl21636194242562}",
      "exercisesTypes":"{2}",
      "genre":3,
      "isPublic":1,
      "language":17,
      "lessonID":"4OEgiM7NizWGER9v7ttJdUQaUCl2134805549011328",
      "maxAge":8,
      "minAge":6,
      "teacherID":"4OEgiM7NizWGER9v7ttJdUQaUCl2",
      "title":"Test lesson 410",
      "totalExercises":1,
      "totalUpvotes":0
   }
}
```

I have checked the JSONs and are both valid. Also the POST request has the same endpoint and the error occurs before handling the data with PHP code.

Has anyone faced something similar or has any idea what can be wrong?

Comment: I wanted to say to check validity of json, but missed the part were you said you did it. Anyways, sometimes mod_security, suhosin find a string in data that they don't like and give a false positive. If the data isn't reaching the php, try looking through the logs, there should be some info about the request.

Comment: @MujnoiGyulaTamas thanks for the response, I will look into it. I also believe that it's a server's issue because this error just appeared without making any changes in the client side.